# AngularJS html unescape inside ng-modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a post text that I can show with ng-bind-html tag in html elements. But I want to write a function where users can edit their posts. So I initiate the ng-modal for the textarea with the encoded text that my backend has encoded. The text has characters such as `&#39;&#39;` And these appear as they are in the textarea when I initiate the ng-modal with the text. How should I populate the textarea and the ng-modal connected to the textarea and show the correct text and allow users to edit their posts?

This is what I have so far:

```
<textarea
    name="title"
    class="textarea post-title-textarea"
    ng-minlength="16"
    ng-maxlength="255"
    required
    mg-autofocus
    ng-model="formData.title"
    textarea-autoresize
></textarea>
```

I tried adding `ng-bind-html="formData.title"` but it still shows the characters that are escaped as long as I also populate the ng-modal with the old text that users will edit.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use ngSanitize which use to parser html.

```
<script src="angular.js">
    <script src="angular-sanitize.js">
```

then include sanitize module in your app

```
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
```

refer : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

### Putting example below:

```
<script>
         angular.module('sanitizeExample', ['ngSanitize'])
           .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
             $scope.snippet =
               '<p style="color:blue">an html\n' +
               '<em onmouseover="this.textContent=\'PWN3D!\'">click here</em>\n' +
               'snippet</p>';
             $scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function() {
               return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.snippet);
             };
           }]);
     </script>
     <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
        Snippet: <textarea ng-model="snippet" cols="60" rows="3"></textarea>
       <table>
         <tr>
           <td>Directive</td>
           <td>How</td>
           <td>Source</td>
           <td>Rendered</td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="bind-html-with-sanitize">
           <td>ng-bind-html</td>
           <td>Automatically uses $sanitize</td>
           <td><pre>&lt;div ng-bind-html="snippet"&gt;<br/>&lt;/div&gt;</pre></td>
           <td><div ng-bind-html="snippet"></div></td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="bind-html-with-trust">
           <td>ng-bind-html</td>
           <td>Bypass $sanitize by explicitly trusting the dangerous value</td>
           <td>
           <pre>&lt;div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()"&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;</pre>
           </td>
           <td><div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()"></div></td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="bind-default">
           <td>ng-bind</td>
           <td>Automatically escapes</td>
           <td><pre>&lt;div ng-bind="snippet"&gt;<br/>&lt;/div&gt;</pre></td>
           <td><div ng-bind="snippet"></div></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
       </div>
```

Hope it would help you.